# Datepicker for date of birth input field

Tags: javascript, php, datepicker

I have a registration portal in which I change its view according to my template and now I want to add an input field to add date of birth with date picker how to use script in this registration page to add date picker.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/stylesheet1.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css" />
    <link href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/register.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="Holder">

    <div id="Navbar">
    <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href ="http://localhost/1/index.php?route=account/login" style="font-size:17px;">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href ="http://localhost/1/index.php?route=account/register" style="font-size:17px;">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href ="http://localhost/1/index.php?route=account/forgotten" style="font-size:17px;">Forgot Password</a></li>
             </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
    <div class="warning"><?php echo $error_warning; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php echo $column_left; ?>
    <div id="content"><?php echo $content_top; ?>
      <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
      <p><?php echo $text_account_already; ?></p>

      <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="Details">
    <div id="YourPersonalDetails">
       <h2><?php echo $text_your_details; ?></h2>
        <div class="content">
          <table class="form">
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_emp_name; ?></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="emp_name" value="<?php echo $emp_name; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_emp_name) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_emp_name; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_emp_ID; ?></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="emp_ID" value="<?php echo $emp_ID; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_emp_ID) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_emp_ID; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><span class="required">*</span> Date Of Birth</td>
                  <td><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="dob" value="<?php echo $dob; ?>" size="12" id="dob" />
                    <?php if ($error_dob) { ?>
                    <span class="error">We require your date of birth!</span>
                    <?php } ?></td>
                </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_email; ?></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_email) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_email; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_mobile_no; ?></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="mobile_no" value="<?php echo $mobile_no; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_mobile_no) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_mobile_no; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="YourAddress" >
        <h2><?php echo $text_your_address; ?></h2>
        <div class="content">
          <table class="form">
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $entry_company; ?></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="company" value="<?php echo $company; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>   

             <tr style="display: <?php echo (count($customer_groups) > 1 ? 'table-row' : 'none'); ?>;">
              <td><?php echo $entry_customer_group; ?></td>
              <td><?php foreach ($customer_groups as $customer_group) { ?>
                <?php if ($customer_group['customer_group_id'] == $customer_group_id) { ?>
                <input type="radio" name="customer_group_id" value="<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>" id="customer_group_id<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>" checked="checked" />
                <label for="customer_group_id<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>"><?php echo $customer_group['name']; ?></label>
                <br />
                <?php } else { ?>
                <input type="radio" name="customer_group_id" value="<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>" id="customer_group_id<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>" />
                <label for="customer_group_id<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>"><?php echo $customer_group['name']; ?></label>
                <br />
                <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>      
            <tr id="company-id-display">
              <td><span id="company-id-required" class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_company_id; ?></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="company_id" value="<?php echo $company_id; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_company_id) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_company_id; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_office_location; ?></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="office_location" value="<?php echo $office_location; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_office_location) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_office_location; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $entry_address_2; ?></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="address_2" value="<?php echo $address_2; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_city; ?></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $city; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_city) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_city; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span id="postcode-required" class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_postcode; ?></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $postcode; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_postcode) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_postcode; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_country; ?></td>
              <td><select name="country_id">
                  <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
                  <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
                  <?php if ($country['country_id'] == $country_id) { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php } ?>
                </select>
                <?php if ($error_country) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_country; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_zone; ?></td>
              <td><select name="zone_id">
              <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
             <option value="1483">Delhi</option>
              <option value="1505">UP</option>





                </select>
                <?php if ($error_zone) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_zone; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr> 
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="YourPassword">
        <h2><?php echo $text_your_password; ?></h2>
        <div class="content">
          <table class="form">
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_password; ?></td>
              <td><input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_password) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_password; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_confirm; ?></td>
              <td><input type="password" name="confirm" value="<?php echo $confirm; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_confirm) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_confirm; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="NewsLetter">
        <h2><?php echo $text_newsletter; ?></h2>
        <div class="content">
          <table class="form">
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $entry_newsletter; ?></td>
              <td><?php if ($newsletter) { ?>
                <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="1" checked="checked" />
                <?php echo $text_yes; ?>
                <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="0" />
                <?php echo $text_no; ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="1" />
                <?php echo $text_yes; ?>
                <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="0" checked="checked" />
                <?php echo $text_no; ?>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>

        <?php if ($text_agree) { ?>
        <div class="buttons">
          <div class="right"><?php echo $text_agree; ?>
            <?php if ($agree) { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" checked="checked" />
            <?php } else { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" />
            <?php } ?>
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_continue; ?>" class="button" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="buttons">
          <div class="right">
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_continue; ?>" class="button" />
          </div>
    </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </form>
      <?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $('input[name=\'customer_group_id\']:checked').live('change', function() {
        var customer_group = [];

    <?php foreach ($customer_groups as $customer_group) { ?>
        customer_group[<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>] = [];
        customer_group[<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>]['company_id_display'] = '<?php echo $customer_group['company_id_display']; ?>';
        customer_group[<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>]['company_id_required'] = '<?php echo $customer_group['company_id_required']; ?>';
        customer_group[<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>]['tax_id_display'] = '<?php echo $customer_group['tax_id_display']; ?>';
        customer_group[<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>]['tax_id_required'] = '<?php echo $customer_group['tax_id_required']; ?>';
    <?php } ?>  

        if (customer_group[this.value]) {
            if (customer_group[this.value]['company_id_display'] == '1') {
                $('#company-id-display').show();
            } else {
                $('#company-id-display').hide();
            }

            if (customer_group[this.value]['company_id_required'] == '1') {
                $('#company-id-required').show();
            } else {
                $('#company-id-required').hide();
            }

            if (customer_group[this.value]['tax_id_display'] == '1') {
                $('#tax-id-display').show();
            } else {
                $('#tax-id-display').hide();
            }

            if (customer_group[this.value]['tax_id_required'] == '1') {
                $('#tax-id-required').show();
            } else {
                $('#tax-id-required').hide();
            }   
        }
    });

    $('input[name=\'customer_group_id\']:checked').trigger('change');
    //--></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $('select[name=\'country_id\']').bind('change', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=account/register/country&country_id=' + this.value,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('select[name=\'country_id\']').after('<span class="wait">&nbsp;<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" alt="" /></span>');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('.wait').remove();
            },          
            success: function(json) {
                if (json['postcode_required'] == '1') {
                    $('#postcode-required').show();
                } else {
                    $('#postcode-required').hide();
                }

                html = '<option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>';

                if (json['zone'] != '') {
                    for (i = 0; i < json['zone'].length; i++) {
                        html += '<option value="' + json['zone'][i]['zone_id'] + '"';

                        if (json['zone'][i]['zone_id'] == '<?php echo $zone_id; ?>') {
                            html += ' selected="selected"';
                        }

                        html += '>' + json['zone'][i]['name'] + '</option>';
                    }
                } else {
                    html += '<option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_none; ?></option>';
                }

                $('select[name=\'zone_id\']').html(html);
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

    $('select[name=\'country_id\']').trigger('change');
    //--></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.colorbox').colorbox({
            width: 640,
            height: 480
        });
    });
    //--></script> 
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: first try you and if you getting error the let us know we will sol. But not directly looking for help from community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jquery date picker. Look at this https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

You just need to use

```
 ("#inputField").Datepicker()
```

Place your html anywhere in the form.

The line above should go inside script> tag

**Update** You need to include jquery files like this in your page's header section

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

Comment: I add the code in my file that I try but this is not working.